# How to solve: $x^2 = \arctan(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm asked to find the area bounded by the curves: $y = x^2$ and y$ = \arctan(x)$. To find the limits of integration, I set the two functions equal to each other and solve for $x$. Finding the left bound as 0 was trivial, but I'm unsure how to solve for the right bound.

$$x^2 = \arctan(x)$$

[image]

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the point of intersection of $ y=x^2$ and $y= \tan ^{-1} x $

With Newton's method and $$f(x) = x^2 - \tan^ {-1} x$$ you get a numerical scheme, $$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac {f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} $$ which converges to the desired solution.

The starting point should be reasonable, such as $x=1$

Answer (score 2):

An antiderivative for $\arctan x$ is
$$
x\arctan x-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2)
$$
so the area you're asked to compute is
$$
\int_0^c (\arctan x-x^2)\,dx=
\Bigl[x\arctan x-\log(1+x^2)-\frac{x^3}{3}\Bigr]_0^c=
c^3-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+c^2)-\frac{c^3}{3}
$$
where $c^2=\arctan c$. Now compute $c$ with an approximation method, if you want an approximation of the result.

With $x_0=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\arctan x}$, I get $x_{10}=0.8336$, which should be exact to four decimals and the integral evaluates to $\approx0.122$.

Comment: I think the main question was about the way to determine $c$.

Answer (score 1):

We can't obtain a closed form for the not trivial solution and we need to proceed by [**numerical methods**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) (Newton's, bisection, etc.).

Here is the numerical solution by [**WolframAlpha**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3Darctan%20x) that is $x \approx 0.833606194406676$.

If you want to obtain the result by yourself let consider $f(x)=x^2-\arctan x$ and use bisection method by a calculator starting for example from

- $x_a=1 \implies f(1)>0$
- $x_b=0.8 \implies f(0.8)<0$

and then we can iteretively get closer and closer to the solution by

- $x_i=\frac{x_a+x_b}2$
- if $f(x_i)>0 \implies x_a=f(x_i)$
- if $f(x_i)<0 \implies x_b=f(x_i)$

Comment: This is not an answer. You need to explain why. Also, maybe the OP is not looking for a closed form but just want to prove the existence of two solutions (which in this case is quite easy).

Comment: @Thinking I'm not sure about your interpretation of the OP. The question is to find the limits of integration that is the not trivial solution for the given equation.

Comment: Ok (note that I am not the one who downvoted).

Comment: @Thinking That's not a problem, I'm always open to discuss different opinion or idea about questions and answers. Do you agree finally with my interpretation?

Comment: Going to an online calculator to calculate an approximation is not the provision of an answer.  Had you used one of the numerical methods you cite, showed how to work with it, to obtain the "numerical approximation", I'd upvote your answer.

Comment: @amWhy I've given an example of numerical determination by bisection method.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes getting you in the ballpark can give you clues as to how to proceed. 
By Taylor Series:
$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+...$

It's integral is : $Tan^{-1}(x)= x-x^3/3+...$

So, solve $x^2=x-x^3/3$. Dividing by $x$ and rearranging:

$x^2/3+x-1=0.$

So by the quadratic formula, Let $x_0=\frac{-1\frac{+}{-}\sqrt{1+4/3}}{2/3}$

Using integration by parts:

$$\int_0^{x_0} Tan^{-1}x-x^2 dx=xTan^{-1}(x)|_0^{x_0} - \int_0^{x_0} \frac{x}{1+x^2}+x^2 dx$$

$$=\frac{2}{3}x_0^3-\frac{1}{2}ln(1+x_0^2)$$

You can tweak $x_0$ some more via Newton's Method or other approximation method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Taylor Series, you can use [Banach's Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

It can be shown that if we have $|x-c|<\epsilon, |f'(x)|<1, $and$ f(x)=x $ then $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon.$

So:

$$x^2=Tan^{-1}(x)$$
$$x=\sqrt{Tan^{-1}(x)}$$
Let $f(x)=\sqrt{Tan^{-1}(x)}$

Then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{Tan^{-1}(x)}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

So $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2x+2x^3}$
We know that $x$ is between $.7$ and $1.0$. So regardless, the derivative is in the correct range.

$$f(1)=\sqrt{\pi}/2=0.88623$$
$$f(\sqrt{\pi}/2)=0.85156$$

It's similar to Newton's method which would have you iterate:

$$x-\frac{x^2-Tan^{-1}(x)}{2x-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$$

So less computational work but somewhat slower speed of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

*For the fun of it.*

You probably know that, better than with Taylor series, we can approximate functions using [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant).

In order to stay with quadratic equations (with one root equal to $0$), let us build around $x=0$ the $[2,n]$ Padé approximant of function
$$f(x)=x^2-\tan ^{-1}(x)=\frac{a^{(n)}_1 x+a^{(n)}_2 x^2}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b^{(n)}_k x^k}$$ making the approximate solution to be
$$x_n=-\frac {a^{(n)}_1  } {a^{(n)}_2  }$$ In fact, the problem simplifies since, for any $n$, $a^{(n)}_1=-1$ making the approximate solution $x_n=\frac {1 } {a^{(n)}_2  }$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_n & x_n \approx \\
 2 & \frac{4}{5}              &  0.800000 \\
 3 & \frac{75}{86}            &  0.872093 \\
 4 & \frac{43}{51}            &  0.843137 \\
 5 & \frac{2142}{2627}        &  0.815379 \\
 6 & \frac{2627}{3161}        &  0.831066 \\
 7 & \frac{47415}{56257}      &  0.842828 \\
 8 & \frac{56257}{67436}      &  0.834228 \\
 9 & \frac{2225388}{2685077}  &  0.828799 \\
 10 & \frac{2685077}{3221304} &  0.833537
\end{array}
\right)$$
For sure, Newton method would be much faster. Using Taylor expansion, we have
$$f(x)=-x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms and solving the quadratic equation gives $x_0=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}-3\right)$ and the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.79128784747792000329 \\
 1 & 0.83600532220715541652 \\
 2 & 0.83361304693610222170 \\
 3 & 0.83360619446291621053 \\
 4 & 0.83360619440667601431
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.